# Escaping ascii code in java

Tags: java, ascii

I want to convert a string say `youru0027s` to `your's` in android.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write this string in your string.xml file as `your\'s`

Comment: Data is coming from server

Comment: Is the server string missing the \?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Will ask them to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
str = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
```

from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

and your string should be `your\u0027s` not `youru0027s` u need to escape unicode via a \u

Comment: Yes, server should return with \u. Since its not returning in that way I got confused.

Comment: @Mathew Checkout my answer it works perfectly.

Comment: If this is only Unicode you can get you can try @GrIsHu answer but if they not returning with \u it gonna be difficult to convert without chances of corruption of string with other Unicode symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Take your coming response in separate string and then try to replace your `u0027` as below:

```
  String m_str="youru0027s";
  m_str=m_str.replaceAll("u0027","'");
```

Comment: server is returning data as youru0027s and not your's

Comment: @Mathew Checkout my answer it works perfectly.